# missing } after property list

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to implement a content slider using jQuery in one of my website; however I keep getting this error:

```
missing } after property list
```

Here is my code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

featuredcontentslider.init({
id: 'slider1',  
contentsource: ['inline', ''],  
toc: '#increment',  
nextprev: ['prev', 'next'], 
revealtype: 'click', 
enablefade: [true, 0.1],  
autorotate: [true, 3000]
});
</script>
```

When I click on view source in Firefox I found that the last curly bracket is missing but in the file the code is fine, and using firebug debug console I got this error:

```
missing } after property list
```

I tried many things, searched for missing commas, eliminate most of the lines but could not find the source of the problem.

EDIT: 
Firebug points to this line:

```
});
```

as the one with error.

I just checked the script in IE8, Chrome and firefox and in all of the three broweser i get the code like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

featuredcontentslider.init({
id: 'slider1',  
contentsource: ['inline', ''],  
toc: '#increment',  
nextprev: ['prev', 'next'], 
revealtype: 'click', 
enablefade: [true, 0.1],  
autorotate: [true, 3000]
);  <---- notice the missing bracket
</script>
```

I also tried to write one line only like so:

```
featuredcontentslider.init({  id: 'slider1'  });
```

and still ended up with the same error. In localhost the script works fine, however in the actual website the script is functioning correctly.

I am wondering is there a possibility that other js code in the page might affect the behaviour of this one?

Comment: Why is the last curly brace missing?

Comment: The bracket shouldn't be just missing from the viewsource of firefox.

Comment: @Slaks that is the actual question

Comment: Try removing all white space between the `()`. If you copy/pasted this code, sometimes an invalid invisible character can find its way in and wreak havok.

Comment: @amosrivera: I'm talking about in View Source. He hasn't provided enough information to answer that question.

Comment: Is this the actual line where the error is reported?

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. I will edit my post to address these issues.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the entire code, and retyping it from scratch? (Start with the simplified version.) Also try removing *all* white space that surrounds that line.

Comment: What encoding have you used in the file where you definied the object?

Answer (score 4):

Hmmm... this smells somewhat like a website cache error.

Perhaps the `}` was missing at one time, and even though you fixed it, your website is still serving the old file.

Have you tried:

- clearing the cache in your browser? (to see if it's browser-side)
- using `curl` or `wget` to view the raw javascript file (to see if there's a stale server-side cache)

Comment: That is what I thought initially, however I never used IE8 to view the website until after the error occurred. Also I used a Firefox plug-in which disables cache (I have used before and it works). I am not familiar with the curl approach, do you mean that I should request the page through curl using php for example?

Comment: Hi, I just pasted your wrong code (i.e. the one with the extra curly bracket) into mine and ran it through Firefox and IE8 and both said that there was an error. I removed the curley brace and both said the code was fine! Have you tried looking at it with a decent editor (like notepad++) which matches up and highlights syntax for blocks of code to see if it can see anything untoward? -- Neil

Comment: @Neil: comment on the original question, or the other answer; your comment isn't relevant to this one.

Comment: @Neil: Yes, I checked it with notepad++ and it did match the extra bracket to any other. For some reasons the page that has the code in my page parses it in a strange way. Perhaps other scripts affected it.

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens, when a property list is accidentally closed by a ";". 
Take a look at the following example (which produces the same error):

```
$('#test').dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    resizable: true,
    draggable: true,
    width:530,
    modal: true,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    show: {
        effect: 'blind',
        duration: 1000
    },
    hide: {
        effect: 'fold',
        duration: 1000
    });
});
```

The ); after

```
hide: { ... });
```

should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I solved the problem by adding an extra curly bracket but I am not sure why that solved the issue. My final script looks like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

featuredcontentslider.init({
id: 'slider1',  
contentsource: ['inline', ''],  
toc: '#increment',  
nextprev: ['prev', 'next'], 
revealtype: 'click', 
enablefade: [true, 0.1],  
autorotate: [true, 3000]
   } <--- notice the extra bracket
});
</script>
```

and it is cross-browser compatible :)

Comment: Whenever I see something like this, it just makes me think that the actual error is with another script that didn't close a braced section.

Comment: Same here. I checked other scripts in the page and they seemed fine. I will give it some extra checking just in case.