# Using Ajax with Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I saw few pages but tried all and none worked for me.

This is what i want:

on my html:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="">
                  <select name="customer_id" id="customer_id" class="form-control">
                    <option>Select customer</option>
                    <?php foreach($customers AS $customer): ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $customer->id;?>"><?php echo $customer->name; ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="category" class="col-xs-4 control-label">Category</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-8">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="category" id="category" placeholder="Category" disabled="disabled">
                </div>
              </div>
```

Then i have a script to auto fill the category field depending on the customer selected, ass on the database each customers fall into different categories.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#customer_id').change(function() {

var customer_id = $("#customer_id").val();

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: <?php echo base_url(). 'customer/getCustomerCat' ; ?>,
data: form_data,
success: function(cat) 
    {
$("#category").val(cat);
}
});
});  

});
</script>
```

Then on my controller i have:

```
public function getCustomerCat(){
$id = $this->input->post('customer_id');
$category = $this->customer_model->getCustomerCat($id)[0]->category;

echo $category;

}
```

On my Model i have:

```
public function getCustomerCat($id){
    $query ="SELECT category FROM customers WHERE id=$id";
    $query = $this->db->query($query);
    return $query->result();
}
```

I am not so good with ajax but expected the categoory field to be populated after selecting a customer without reloading the page.

Comment: Do you receive an error or data back from the ajax request? Use firebug or chrome developer tools to see if there is a return from the database or an error. Using firebug, you should see the ajax call and return on the console, in Chrome Dev Tools it is under the Network tab.

Comment: im getting a syntax error "SyntaxError: missing } after property list"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726686/missing-after-property-list
Perhaps one too many )};'s?